# Print all mongoDB data to string nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a sample mongo document like this:

```
> db.chat.find().pretty()
{
    "_id": ObjectId("555f1c0c7f4b820758b439b0"),
    "user": "Guest1",
    "friend": [{
        "userfriend": "Guest2",
        "noidung": [{
            "method": "send",
            "date": "2015-05-22T19:11:34+07:00",
            "content": "allloooo"
        }, {
            "method": "receive",
            "date": "2015-05-23T09:08:14+07:00",
            "content": "yes man"
        }]
    }, {
        "userfriend": "Guest3",
        "noidung": [{
            "method": "send",
            "date": "2015-05-23T15:42:34+07:00",
            "content": "foo 15:42"
        }, {
            "method": "receive",
            "date": "2015-05-23T15:42:45+07:00",
            "content": "bar 15:43"
        }]
    }]
}
```

And in my server.js, i use this code to print all data:

```
var chathistory = db.collection('chat');
chathistory.find().toArray(function (err, docs) {
    console.log(docs)
});
```

And i get this log in my terminal:

```
[ { _id: 555f1c0c7f4b820758b439b0,
    user: 'Guest1',
    friend: [ [Object], [Object] ] } ]
```

'friend' field doesn't print all, its only `[Object]`, so how can i get full data.

Comment: You have to use json.stringify(docs) .

Comment: @shreya `console.log(require('util').inspect(docs, { showHidden: true, depth: null }));` will also work

Comment: Tks @shreya:) you save my time

Comment: but json.stringify() is more simple to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To print all the data, use the **[`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** method

```
db.collection('chat').find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(docs));
});
```